# QtCreator doesn't open on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, segmentation-fault, qt-creator

**Problem:**

I need to install Qt Creator for my university course on my mac and it doesn't open. I've tried reinstalling different versions a lot of times but it gives me a Segmentation Fault everytime.
Everything else is updated to the latest Version and i don't know what to try anymore.
Any tips and solutions would be appreciated.

**This is one of the error messages:**

```
DebuggerItem \"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb\" ({8999bbd1-bcb9-4fd1-843a-47fec36eb8b6}) read from \"/Users/Samy/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/debuggers.xml\" dropped since the command is not executable."
zsh: segmentation fault  /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Qt\ Creator
```

**Here is the Report if I try opening the App:**

```
Process:               Qt Creator [54924]
Path:                  /Applications/Qt Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Qt Creator
Identifier:            org.qt-project.qtcreator
Version:               4.11.0 (4.11.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Qt Creator [54924]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-01-08 22:12:42.699 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15 (19A602)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        103F9158-D5E0-F1B8-BA89-222AB7C6F587

Sleep/Wake UUID:       3FB53B09-90D6-4FB8-AB3A-2D663E75701E

Time Awake Since Boot: 170000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       15000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [54924]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010d082000-000000010d096000 [   80K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Qt Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Qt Creator

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libUtils.4.11.0.dylib           0x000000010d1ab7b0 QtPrivate::QFunctorSlotObject<Utils::FancyMainWindowPrivate::FancyMainWindowPrivate(Utils::FancyMainWindow*)::$_2, 1, QtPrivate::List<bool>, void>::impl(int, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, QObject*, void**, bool*) + 48
1   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010e3369b5 0x10e10f000 + 2259381
2   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x000000010d3f040e QAction::setChecked(bool) + 174
3   libDebugger.dylib               0x0000000114a1a2ef Utils::DebuggerMainWindow::restorePersistentSettings() + 1151
4   libDebugger.dylib               0x0000000114a19c5d Utils::DebuggerMainWindow::DebuggerMainWindow() + 925
5   libDebugger.dylib               0x0000000114a218fb Utils::Perspective::Perspective(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) + 267
6   libDebugger.dylib               0x0000000114a24d25 Debugger::Internal::DebuggerPluginPrivate::DebuggerPluginPrivate(QStringList const&) + 1781
7   libDebugger.dylib               0x0000000114a36747 Debugger::Internal::DebuggerPlugin::initialize(QStringList const&, QString*) + 39
8   libExtensionSystem.4.11.0.dylib 0x000000010d0cbecb ExtensionSystem::Internal::PluginSpecPrivate::initializePlugin() + 107
9   libExtensionSystem.4.11.0.dylib 0x000000010d0be6a0 ExtensionSystem::Internal::PluginManagerPrivate::loadPlugin(ExtensionSystem::PluginSpec*, ExtensionSystem::PluginSpec::State) + 656
10  libExtensionSystem.4.11.0.dylib 0x000000010d0b6f90 ExtensionSystem::Internal::PluginManagerPrivate::loadPlugins() + 592
11  org.qt-project.qtcreator        0x000000010d08de28 main + 14520
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6e91b405 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb245b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb245b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb245b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb245b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb245b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6ea6b7c6 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3764a92a __CFSocketManager + 632
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb27d76 _pthread_start + 125
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6eb245d7 thread_start + 15

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007ffee2b7cf50  rdx: 0x0000600000d5a3c0
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x000060000184bba0  rbp: 0x00007ffee2b7ce70  rsp: 0x00007ffee2b7ce60
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000000011c7d7be0  r11: 0x000000010d5461d0
  r12: 0x0000600003c9bea0  r13: 0x000000011c805d40  r14: 0x0000000000000001  r15: 0x0000600000d5a3c0
  rip: 0x000000010d1ab7b0  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004 (no mapping for user data write)
Trap Number:     14

[Number jibberish]`enter code here`


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 114998
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=780.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=780.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=573.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=573.9M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               128K        1 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                  248K        2 
CoreImage                            8K        2 
CoreUI image data                   72K        1 
JS VM register file               4360K        4 
JS VM register file (reserved)    2040K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           167.2M       43 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        7 
Stack                             11.0M        7 
VM_ALLOCATE                        132K        9 
WebAssembly memory                4096K        1 
__DATA                            39.4M      428 
__DATA_CONST                        41K        3 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__GLSLBUILTINS                    5176K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       382.9M      106 
__OBJC_RO                         31.8M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1764K        2 
__TEXT                           397.2M      410 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                      332.3M       43 
shared memory                      640K       15 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.8G     1096 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.4G     1096 

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM 190.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 1,6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics6000Item, Intel HD Graphics 6000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.105.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1429)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.0f8, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121,33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Comment: Where did you get the installer and how did you install it?

Comment: Looks like https://forum.qt.io/topic/110447/qtcreator-segfault-on-startup-macos , try the suggestion there

Comment: Not sure how to start it without Plugins, but i tried deleting the debugger Plugin and it opens now but i can't create a new Projekt, since the kit for it doesn't work aswell as the debugger apperantly

Comment: From the official website and I installed the Qt charts, Qt data visualization and Qt Network Authorization as told in the guide from my university but it was for windows with other options so not very helpful

Comment: It  kinda works if i use Qbs as a Build-system (debugger plugin deleted) but not with qmake and i can't debug which is still a major problem

Comment: When running a program you get a segfault, you may bet that you have found a bug in (or around) that program. I would create a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/) for Qt Creator and attach the crash report to it.